# how to fix: This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:deploy_production script can't be blank

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying GitLab for my first example.
I can't see where's is the error here:

this is for windows running firebase, vue.js, node.js on gitlab

```
image: node:alpine
cache:
paths: 
   - node_modules/

deploy_production:
     stage: deploy
     environment: Production
     only:
        - master  
script: 
      - npm install
      - npm i -g firebase tools
      - npm run build 
      - firebase deploy --non-interactive --token "1/CYHKW-CuYsKOcy2Eo6_oC9akwGjyqtmtRZok93xb5VY"
```

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:deploy_production script
>   can't be blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can get this error message:

Here's what I was trying to do in gitlab-ci.yml:

```
default:
  cache:
    paths:
      - .gradle
```

And I was getting this error message:

> jobs:default script can't be blank

I was using the documentation here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

Which clearly indicates how to use default. The message implies gitlab thought default was a job.

**ANSWER**

You probably know where this is going -- the version I was using was about 3 years behind latest, and the "default" keyword had been added since then.

Check the version of gitlab you're using by going to the Help page (gitlab.domain.com/help), and it's listed at the top of the page.

To find the right documentation, I went to https://gitlab.com/rluna-gitlab/gitlab-ce, then chose my version from the branch drop down. From there went to the docs folder, then clicked on this link in the Popular Documentation table in the README.

https://gitlab.com/rluna-gitlab/gitlab-ce/-/blob/11-6-stable/doc/ci/yaml/README.md

Comment: Thanks, I give this advice all the time but forgot to follow it myself today :P

Answer (score 1):

You specify a `stage` in your `deploy_production` job but you don't define `stages`.

Add :

```
stages:
  - deploy
```

before your job definition.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but one problem here is the indenting of the script tag, which needs to be under the job deploy_production. script isn't allowed at the top level like you've shown it here.

The error is kind of confusing, but does indicate the situation. Because script isn't at the right indent level, it's not part of the job, and a job requires a script.

Should be:

```
deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm install
```

Another issue is you should screen out your token in the post!